# ng-click - after click do function and redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

I have little problem.

I want to create ng-click with redirect, but before redirect I need to post some data.

My html code :

```
<a href="/test" ng-click="updateData($event)">Go</a>
```

My angular updateData function :

```
$scope.updateData = function($event){

   $event.preventDefault();

   $http.post(someAddress, $scope.data)
      .success(function(){
          // on success redirect
      });
   };
```

I found somethings like this `scope.$eval(clickAction);` but I don;t know how I should use it.

I can't use only redirect without JS because I have 2 different forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="/test" ng-click="updateData($event, this.href)">Go</a>


$scope.updateData = function($event, loc){
   $event.preventDefault();

   $http.post(someAddress, $scope.data)
      .success(function(){
          // on success redirect
          location.href = loc;
      });
   };
```

Comment: Thank you guys. It slove my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should redirect from JS function rather than relying on `href`, no need of `$event.preventDefault();` in this case.

**Markup**

```
<a href="" ng-click="updateData()">Go</a>
```

**Code**

```
 $scope.updateData = function(){
    $http.post(someAddress, $scope.data)
    .success(function(){
      // on success redirect
      $location.path('/test'); //to redirect from here
    });
 };
```

Comment: Native JS is always faster than any frameworks helper functions.

Comment: i don't think so..rather than doing it..I will follow more angular way of coding..

Answer (score 1):

For full redirects, try the following:

```
location.assign("http://someuri.com");
```